# Копировать документацию из базового класса

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Подскажите, можно ли в Visual Studio как-нибудь сделать так, что бы если у меня интерфейс задокументирован и я где-то сделал его реализацию, то я мог бы скопировать документацию из базового класса или интерфейса?

В Resharper такая фича есть, но ставить его только ради этого не хочется.

Comment: [Оно](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/inheritdoc)?

Comment: inheritdoc должно подойти, но также есть расширение GhostDoc, которое будет копировать доки из базового класса